# How to send CLI commands using PowerShell once connected

Tags: powershell, ssh, pulse

I've created an SSH keypair which I'm using to connect to a Pulse VTM (Linux based load balancer appliance) via SSH over Powershell. This part works fine, but I can't seem to send any further commands via my script once the keypair has authenticated. Everything I put in after the authentication seems to get ignored. I'm trying to send the command 'zcli' [enter]. Can someone point me in the right direction for how to stream commands in my script after this point? Invoke-Command doesn't seem to work.

It seems to break at this point:

```
#Connect to VTM via SSH
ssh admin@**IPADDRESS**

#Initiate ZCLI prompt
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "zcli"
```

---

### Script

```
#Make sure Powershell is running in 64bit mode
if (($pshome -like "*syswow64*") -and ((Get-WmiObject 
Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -like "64*")) {
    write-warning "Restarting script under 64 bit powershell"

    # relaunch this script under 64 bit shell
    & (join-path ($pshome -replace "syswow64", 
"sysnative")\powershell.exe) -file $myinvocation.mycommand.Definition 
@args

    # This will exit the original powershell process. This will only be 
done in case of an x86 process on a x64 OS.
exit
}

#Bypass Execution Policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -force

#Connect to VTM via SSH
ssh admin@**IPADDRESS**

#Initiate ZCLI prompt
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "zcli"

#Create Pool
Pool.addPool ["Sam_Test"],[["10.10.10.10:443","10.10.10.11:80"]]
Pool.setLoadBalancingAlgorithm ["Sam_Test"], roundrobin
Pool.setPassiveMonitoring ["Sam_Test"], 0
Pool.setMonitors ["Sam_Test"], "Simple HTTPS"
Pool.setKeepalive ["Sam_Test"], 1
Pool.setSSLEncrypt ["Sam_Test"], 1
```

My script logs on fine but then runs no further commands?

Comment: I am assuming you are using `Posh-SSH` Module. If so, you need to create a `New-SSHSession`. Then you can send commands using `Invoke-SSHCommand` by Index. Example: `New-SSHSession -ComputerName 10.1.1.1 -credendital (Get-Credential)` . Then send your commands by session Index: `Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -comand "uname"`. If you dont know your index (or it is different), just use `Get-SSHSession` the far left value will be the index.

Comment: Hi there, Posh-SSH module didn't work for me after several days of trying to use it so I'm using the new native SSH commands in Powershell released recently in the Fall Creators update (update 1709)